# Upload Multiple Files from React Dropzone and Send to Backend

Tags: reactjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { CSSProperties } from "react";
import Navbar from "../../components/Header/Navbar";
import Footer from "../../components/Footer/Footer";
import pdf from "../../assets/static/img/icons/pdf.png";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import axios from "axios";

function MergePdf() {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File[]>([]);
  const [word, setword] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [wordurl, setwordurl] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps } = useDropzone({
    accept: {
      "application/pdf": [".pdf"],
    },

    maxFiles: 5,
    maxSize: 1000000,

    onDrop: (acceptedFiles: File[]) => {
      console.log("Files dropped:", acceptedFiles);

      setSelectedFile(acceptedFiles);
    },
  });

  const handleUpload = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
        const formData = new FormData();

        // Append each file to the FormData
        selectedFile.forEach((file) => {
          formData.append("files", file);
        });

        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://127.0.0.1:8000/pdf/merge-pdf-file",
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
            },
          }
        );

        console.log("Server Response:", response.data);

        const newpdf = response.data.file_paths || [];
        const pdfurl = newpdf[0];
        console.log(pdfurl);
        setwordurl(pdfurl);

        // Extract file names from URLs
        const fileNames = newpdf.map((pdfurl: String) => {
          const urlParts = pdfurl.split("/");
          return urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];
        });
        setword(fileNames);

        console.log("Success:");
      } else {
        console.error("No file selected");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error uploading file:", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedFile) {
      handleUpload();
    }
  }, [selectedFile]);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div id="mainHeading" className="me-4">
        <div className="container col d-flex align-items-center ">
          <img
            id="headingImg"
            src={pdf}
            alt="Youtube Image"
            height="60"
            width="80"
          />

          <h1 className="fs-1 fw-bold"> Merge Pdf</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="container d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center mt-5">
        <section
          {...getRootProps({ className: "dropzone bg-warning" })}
          style={dropzoneStyles}
        >
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {loading ? (
            <div>
              <span role="status" className="text-dark fw-bold">
                Fetching{" "}
              </span>
              <span
                className="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm"
                // className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"
                aria-hidden="true"
              ></span>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <b className="text-dark">
              Drag & drop files OR click to select files
            </b>
          )}
        </section>
      </div>

      <div className="container mt-5 col d-flex align-items-center   justify-content-center">
        {word.length > 0 && (
          <table className="yttable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>File Name</th>
                <th>Download</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {word.map((fileName, index) => (
                <tr key={index}>
                  <td>{fileName}</td>
                  <td>
                    <a
                      className="btn btn-warning fw-bold m-2"
                      href={wordurl || ""}
                      rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    >
                      Download File
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        )}
      </div>

      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default MergePdf;

const dropzoneStyles: CSSProperties = {
  borderRadius: "4px",
  padding: "20px",
  textAlign: "center",
  cursor: "pointer",
  width: "22rem",
  height: "5rem",
  display: "flex",
  alignContent: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
};
```

I make pdf merge project on python that accept multiple files from frontend. In my case dropzone only accept one file and merge it. APi Request pattern is below:

```js
{
  "files": "http://example.com"
}
```

Challenge:
The backend API doesn't support indexing, so using indices for files (e.g., files[0], files[1]) in the request is not a viable solution.
Question:
How can I modify the Dropzone.js implementation or the file handling logic to allow Dropzone to accept and send an array of files to the backend API for PDF merging?